# ERROR in DB2 stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, java-stored-procedures

What is wrong with following stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST
     (IN mbr VARCHAR(30),
      OUT sql_state CHAR(5)
    ) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL BEGIN DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
DECLARE rs CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR
    SELECT
            *
        FROM
            A.XYZ;
OPEN rs;
SET
sql_state = SQLSTATE;

END @;
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: it is DB2 SQ ERROR: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601

Comment: Is this normal?  `END @;`??

Answer (score 0):

According to Info Center, [SQL Code `-104`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n104.htm) means that you have an illegal symbol somewhere. In the full error message, it should give an indication to where that illegal symbol is located.

My guess is that something is confused about your statement terminators, have a look at [this article](http://eddyleesinti.blogspot.com/2007/12/db2-changing-statement-terminator.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in command editor then you simply need to

> Change your default termination character from semi-colon (;) to something
>   else

and it will work.

You can see the IBM TechNote here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224723